# Como achar uma informação de uma tag xml usando o xPath no Postgresql?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, xml

Eu queria usar o comando `xPath`, mas não sei ao certo como funciona.

Eu tenho uma tabela e dentro dela uma coluna que armazena `XML's`.
Eu gostaria de realizar uma consulta que trouxesse o valor que está dentro dessa *tag* como um texto.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Para consultar esse informação da coluna, sugiro usar o comando `like` do `sql`: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp     O comando xPath tu queria usar em qual programa ou linguagem de programação?

Comment: Vou usar no JAVA, a questão é que essa consulta vai ser usada em situações em que essa TAG pode ser alterada, eu sei qual é a TAG, mas como a informação dentro dela pode mudar... :/

Comment: Tu consegue pegar o xPath então? E depois tu quer ver o que tem no caminho? Seria Isso?

Comment: A situação é assim:
- Eu sei que existe o comando xPath, mas não sei como usar ele
- Eu sei que se eu faço SELECT colunacomxml FROM tabela, eu consigo pegar todo o código XML
- O que eu preciso é trazer na consulta, apenas um determinado valor que tá dentro desse XML

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [xpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-xml.html):

```
xpath( xpath_exp , xml [ , nsarray ])
```

A função `xpath` avalia a expressão `xpath_exp` em relação ao valor `xml` e Rretorna uma matriz de valores XML correspondentes ao conjunto de nós produzido pela expressão XPath.

O segundo argumento deve ser um documento `XML` bem formado.

O terceiro argumento, opcional da função, é uma matriz de mapeamentos de namespaces.

---

Criei um tabela chamada `teste` com dois elemento `id` que é `INT`e `conteudo` que é `XML`. 
Inseri duas linhas com esquema ligeiramente diferente. Ambas possui o root chamado `<raiz>` mas diferem no primeiro descendente uma é `<teste1>` e a outra é `<teste2>`.
Então faço o select com a seguinte expressão XPath `'//teste1'`:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```sql
CREATE TABLE teste (
  id INT,
  conteudo XML
);

INSERT INTO teste (id, conteudo) VALUES (1, xmlparse(document '<?xml version="1.1"?><raiz><teste1>Yeah!!Serei selecionado com XPath</teste1></raiz>'));
INSERT INTO teste (id, conteudo) VALUES (2, xmlparse(document '<?xml version="1.1"?><raiz><teste2>Hum... não irei ser selecionado com XPath</teste2></raiz>'));
```

---

**Query #1**

```sql
SELECT xpath('//teste1', conteudo) FROM teste;
```

**Resultado**

> Query #1 Execution time: 1ms
>
> | xpath                                                  |
>
> | ------------------------------------------------------ |
>
> | {"Yeah!!Serei selecionado com XPath"} |
>
> | {}                                                     |